# Application Server v Database Server

Tags: database, vb.net, server, client

I am currently working on designing a project to be developed in VB.NET using Visual Studio 2010.

The project will be a database access application used to manage records of staff training attendance. Multiple users will be accessing the application at the same time and it needs to work over the internet.

My question is should I have the database server directly connected to the internet for this or should I create an application server for the project and host it on the local network and channel all database queries through it.

There will be the need for some workflow and data routing as well as background job workers but im not sure if I do this as a complete application server and the clients access the data through the application server or if they should access the data directly on the database server and simply write a server program which only handles the workflow routing and background job workers.

Any advice on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Your primary consideration here isn't really one of software development, but one of infrastructure security.  Which of the two options will be simpler to secure and present less risk to the business?  Exposing a database to the internet, or exposing a web server to the internet?  The difference in software architecture between the two is minimal, it's just a matter of communication channel implementations between your application layers.

Comment: Sorry but this site is for answers, not advice. Your question is likely to solicit debate so I have voted to close it.